# MongoDB Atlas trigger offline sync skipping trigger

Tags: mongodb, triggers, realm, mongodb-atlas

I am using MongoDB Realm to sync Mobile app with Atlas. I also have a trigger to listen to change stream  and post data to an external API. Whenever user performs a transaction in the app, it comes to Atlas and invokes the trigger which posts the data to the API. Each transaction invokes a trigger.

##### Architecture and Workflow:

- React Native App uses Realm and subscribe to a collection in MongoDB Atlas. Each document contains a set of fields including numbers, strings, dates and array.
- App user submits a form which syncs data with Atlas collection.
- As data is submitted to Atlas, a trigger is invoked which posts the latest synced data to an external API. Trigger is written in Node.js
- Each form submission in the app invokes a trigger

This works fine in on-line mode. In case user performs transactions offline and then comes online, the data is sent to Atlas but only the latest trigger is invoked (confirmed via logs)

How can I handle this to get all offline transactions to triggers, not just the latest one?

##### A Workaround:

It seems that MongoDB Atlas triggers are intended to be triggered by specific events or at scheduled times, rather than being used for processing historical changes in batches.

Let's consider a scenario where a user updates some measurements inside the app multiple times while offline. When the user goes online, Realm syncs the batch of transactions with the collection in MongoDB Atlas. However, the trigger treats this batch as a single transaction and only sends the latest value to the external service.

To address this issue, we can implement a workaround by using a dedicated collection to track the transactions that require processing. This means that whenever an update is made in the app, it will be sent to both the data collection and the transactional collection.

Here's the workflow:

1. Create a new collection to track the transactions:
   We can create a new collection called `triggerQueue` to store the transactions that need processing by the trigger. Each time an update is made in the app, it will be stored in the relevant collection as well as in the `triggerQueue`. The `triggerQueue` collection will also include a field called `isSynced` to determine the sync status of each document.
2. Modify the trigger:
   We will modify the existing triggers to listen to the change stream of the `triggerQueue` collection. Any documents in the `triggerQueue` with the `isSynced` field set to false will be processed by submitting them to the Azure functions or AMP. Once a document is successfully submitted, the `isSynced` field will be set to true.

By following this approach, we can ensure that all relevant updates are processed correctly and that the trigger works as expected, even for historical changes made while the app was offline.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is not clear what the structure of the data changed while offline is. Say you're updating a single field, then all the changes that were made offline will be uploaded together and the server may opportunistically batch them when applying them to the database in Atlas. This is because Atlas Device Sync makes guarantees about the final state of the data converging, but no guarantees about the process by which convergence is achieved.

If that is undesirable and you need the trigger to be invoked about each change, you probably want to restructure your data model so that you persist the mutating operations and sync those. E.g. rather than have a model like (all examples are js-based pseudocode since you haven't specified the language you're using):

```
class Counter {
    int value;
}
```

And do mutations like:

```
realm.write(() => {
    myCounter.value++;
});
```

You would have a class like:

```
class Counter {
    List<CounterOperation> operations;
    int value => operations.sum(o => o.value);
}

class CounterOperation {
    int value;
}
```

and use it like:

```
realm.write(() => {
    myCounter.operations.add(new CounterOperation { value = 1 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the original question for clarity. 

As I have mentioned in the question, the workflow works fine in on-line mode. So if a user submits 2 forms, trigger invokes twice which is confirmed by the logs. 

When the user submits these 2 transactions in off-line mode and then comes online, only one trigger fires with the latest transaction. However, Atlas stores both transactions,.

Does your example covers for this scenario?

Comment: If you insert two objects in Realm and only get the trigger invoked for one of them, regardless of whether the device was offline or online, this sounds like a bug and you should probably contact support so they can investigate what exactly is going on.